# Automate copying data from sharepoint Excel files on sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

We are using Sharepoint drive within different teams. MY Operation team upload daily report for Sharepoint where I have read access. month-wise folders are done and one report file per day with the same structure.
I am trying to automate copying data from the Sharepoint folder excel daily files. The problem found is that automation to search through the Sharepoint folder does not work for the company Sharepoint.
When I run the same code for a set of files on a local drive (say D drive) code works fine.

How do I search through the Sharepoint folder OPEN, copy and close files using VBA?

sample code below

```
Sub GetPath()
' This sub enables file dialog box and allows to select a file desired
Dim FilePicker As FileDialog
Dim sharepath As Variant
Dim aFile As String ' this is file name extracted from sharepoint


Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FilePicker
    .InitialFileName = "xxx mysahrepoint path"
    .Title = "Please select your file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Confirm"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        fle = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        End
    End If
End With

If fle = "" Then
MsgBox ("No file is selected")
ElseIf fle <> "" Then
MsgBox ("Selected file name is " & fle)
End If
' Once the above MSGBOX appears with file path after file selection it means the sharepoint connection successful and file selected.
' Once successful comment the if block as it is required only for check
aFile = Right(fle, Len(fle) - InStrRev(fle, "/"))
sharepath = Left(fle, Len(fle) - Len(aFile))

MsgBox sharepath

myfile = Dir(sharepath)

    Do While Len(myfile) > 0
    
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Mid(myfile, 3, 1) <> "C" Then
        MsgBox "myfile"
        ans = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
            If flag = "No" Then
            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
            
    myfile = Dir
    
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no easy way to do this with SharePoint (though if anyone knows one I'd like to hear about it). You might consider syncing a local folder with the folder you need to scan and using the local copy instead.

Comment: If I interpret correctly, then do you hint to download the SharePoint files, update data/ VBA work and then upload back to Sharepoint?

Comment: Not download, but use the Sharepoint "Sync" feature.

Comment: You can upload file in SharePoint Document library and you can make use of power automate's trigger "When a file is created (properties only)" to upload recently added files data to SharePoint list